# How to dynamically create a sqlite3 database on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, dynamic

I would like to know if it is possible to create the file of a database by programming? 
Actually I need to create a database if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you have your own valid reasons for using sqlite3 directly rather than Core Data.  There are certainly cases where it's appropriate.

The `sqlite_3_open()` function will create the database if it doesn't already exist.  The `sqlite3_open_v2()` function will create the database if you pass `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` in the `flags` parameter.  See [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) for more details.

Of course on iPhone you'll need to make sure you're creating the database in a read-write directory such as the app's Documents directory, as opposed to the Resources directory, which is read-only.

In practice I've never tried building a database from the ground up on the iPhone.  I always found it simpler to just include an empty DB file with the schema pre-built as an application resource, and then copy the file to the Documents directory the first time the app is run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need to create the database file directly? Maybe you should check out the [Core Data Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I have never used Core Data so I will have a look on this.

For the moment I also copy a DB file from the Resource directory to the Documents but I would like to create a static library which can be used by many persons. So I would give a minimum of files to add to their project. That's the reason.